# Insert into multiple tables in lumen (laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

i try to insert some data into 2 tables with lumen. I use lumen as REST Api.

This i have made:

**Create Route:**

```
$router->group(['prefix' => 'fp'], function () use ($router) {
    $router->post('/OnUVCreate/{idfach}/{idjahrgang}/{SendUVorhaben}', 'UVCreateController@postuvorhaben'); 
});
```

**And my Controller:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class UVCreateController extends Controller
{
    
    public function postuvorhaben($idfach, $idjahrgang, $SendUVorhaben)
     {
     
       $dbuvorhaben = DB::table('uvorhaben')
            ->insert(
            ['uvorhaben'=> $SendUVorhaben]
            );
       $id = DB::getPdo()->;
       $dbfju = DB::table('faecherJahrgangUvorhaben')
            ->insert(
            ['fachID'=> $idfach],
            ['jahrgangID'=> $idjahrgang],
            ['uvorhabenID'=> $id]
            );
            
            
             return response()->json(['message' => 'ok'], 200);
     }
    
    
}
```

The half of them works. The first insert works fine. The second insert doesnt work. He insert "fachID" correct but "jahrgangID" and "uvorhabenID"
he didnt insert.

Sorry for my bad english and thank you very much for your help!
Greetings
Sascha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

insert method to `faecherJahrgangUvorhaben` table is wrong. You have created multiple array for single insert i guess.

```
$dbfju = DB::table('faecherJahrgangUvorhaben')
            ->insert(
            [
            'fachID'=> $idfach,
            'jahrgangID'=> $idjahrgang,
            'uvorhabenID'=> $id
           ]
            );
```

I suggest you create Models for each table.So it will avoid redundant code.For example suppose if db table name changes then you have change multiple places .